# how to add Closable admob banner to android app

Tags: android, admob

I added Admon to my android app.
what I want to do, add a Closable banner that has "X" that allows the user to close the banner 
i've seen many apps do that.

Comment: Please add what you tried in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust button on Banner and set visibility on button click

```
btnCloseAd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adView.destroy();
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```